# How to formulate a reminder regarding letter of financial support?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, email, canada

I have received my admission letter for a graduate program from a Canadian university. However, the letter contains no information about funding. I have already talked to my professor about the availability of funding. I contacted him again more than one month ago and he said that he will send me a letter of financial support. So far he has not sent me said letter. What should I write to ask him again for this letter? Could you please tell me how I can contact him or provide a template email? I am an international student and I need to apply for the visa.
Best, 
Nikki

Answer (score 3):

I would write something along the lines of:

> Hello Professor,
>
> I am writing to follow up on the letter of financial support we had
>   discussed a while back. I was wondering if you had a chance to write
>   it, or if you needed more documentation from me. Please let me know if
>   I need to do anything on my end.
>
> Best,  Nikki

Comment: I like the formulation a lot and I upvoted it.  But I think it fits better for the first reminder.  Now, it's time for an email that shows some of the student's consternation about the visa, OR BETTER YET, a phone call.  If you can't reach the prof, talk to a department administrator.

Comment: I sent an email like this. again he said I will send you the financial support letter. But he did not send me anything. Could you send me a template of an email which shows my concern about visa process?